Change order/presentation level of agents in agent population
I want to create a map with clickable regions from a shapefile, however some regions have inner borders with different regions inside.
I've got a population of agents, each agent represensting one region. Each agent has a clickable  group to which I add the shape(s) of the region as one or multiple ShapePolyLine objects at simulation start.
When one region/group is within another I can only click the outer/larger one.
So far I've only seen two possibilities:

Create polylines with holes in the middle. This does not work as far as I know.
Add the inner polylines after the outer ones. The last added polyline is displayed at the top, however is still not clickable when inside another polyline.

I also tried to work with presentation indices, couldn't get anywhere there either tho.
Here a picture to illustrate the problem:

It's not perfectly clear but when hovering above the inner red region as in the right picture the outer green region is selected.
Any idea how to get the inner region clickable would be greatly appreciated. I could probably change my approach to the agent based regions as well if that helps.
Best regards and thanks in advance!
Edit:
Created an MRE in a github repo:
https://github.com/theRealLukasMeier/AnylogicOverlappingAgentsMRE

You can programmatically change the stacking order of shapes using simple code.
For example, to send a shape to the back, use:
myShape.presentation.remove(rectangle);
myShape.presentation.insert(0, rectangle);

You can find all calls here: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/presentation/editing-presentation-shapes.html#changing-the-shapersquos-z-order-at-model-runtime

Thank you for the answer, I've seen this before but I don't think this quite works for my problem. For one as I add the shapes at runtime I can't (maybe I can, I haven't found a way tho) directly add the shapes to the main agent but have to add them to groups instead. This might still not be a problem, however each group with its own region-shapes is in its own agent as Visble on upper agent.
After sleeping over it I think my implementation doesn't allow ordering the regions so I must look for ways to adjust it there. Removing region line colors allows me to import shapefiles differently.

if it is in separate agents, you can sort the agent presentation shapes on Main the same way

I will look into that a bit more but I think it doesn't work when using a population of agents as the population shows up directly under Presentation instead of Presentation>level.
To clarify, I have a population of agents built from a database with ~700 regions, each region is its own agent in the population with a group of polylines representing its shape. The purpose is to make the region shapes clickable and view the region overview.

best edit the original question or ask a new one with these details. SOF does not work like a forum but is a Q&A place, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow
